# Only write logs for custom logging

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-extensions-logging

I am following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I am trying to only log my own custom logging in a asp.net core 3.1 API. And not all logs generated from asp.net core. I have created a blank weather forecast service:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    _logger.LogTrace("LogTrace");
    _logger.LogDebug("LogDebug");
    _logger.LogInformation("LogInformation");
    _logger.LogError("LogError");

    var rng = new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Trace",
      "TestAPI": "Trace"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "InstrumentationKey": "xx-xx-x-x-xx",
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "Microsoft": "Trace",
        "TestAPI": "Trace"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I have following nuget installed both version 2.14.0:
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore

Now I try to run the app, but gets no logs.

I try adding services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(); to startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Same no logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note that the `ApplicationInsights` key means two very different things depending on where it's located in the JSON file.

If the key is on the JSON root level (ie. what you call "outside"), it's used to configure Application Insights, and it's where you specify your instrumentation key. It looks like this:

```js
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "Instrumentationkey":"xxx-36a5-4687-b1fc-xxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Second, if it's located inside the `Logging` section, it's used to configure the [`ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger), which determines which log level is sent to Application Insights. That's the `ILogger` [log filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-filtering) mechanism.

By default, only log levels `warning` or higher are sent to app insights. If you only want to send all your logs to application insights, you can either configure it for your namespaces, or ignore the messages coming from the `System` and `Microsoft` namespaces:

```js
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace"
        "System": "None",
        "Microsoft": "None"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was so caught up in the other answer. Your totally correct. Key needs to be outside!

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, there is no need to put those provider settings outside "Logging" (you shouldn't). 
Every logging setting you want should be put inside only ( unless there is a provider configured to specifically read that)

Now to answer your question, let's say that your application's root namespace is `MyNetCore`. ( it would be similar to the name of the project).

> If you are using Visual Studio, You can view your Project's root namespace from Project Properties -> Application -> Default Namespace

To view logs from your application only, you have to set the default logging level to `None` and logging level of your project `MyNetCore` to `Trace`

[**Edit:** You have set the logging levels for `ApplicationInsights` (or any other provider) separately. The default one is for `kestrel`.]

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "None",
        "MyNetCore": "Trace"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "xxx-36a5-4687-b1fc-xxxxxx",
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "None",
            "MyNetCore": "Trace"
        }
    }
}
```

> The Logging level set here is the `minimum` level. 
> If you set it to Trace (0), all the log levels (greater than 0) will be shown. i.e. From `Information` to `Critical` 
>   If you set it to None (6), no logs will be shown
>   
> Reference to different Log Levels : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel

If you want to view only errors from asp.net core, and every log level from your application, then you can do this.

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "None",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "MyNetCore": "Trace"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "xxx-36a5-4687-b1fc-xxxxxx",
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "None",
            "Microsoft": "Error",
            "MyNetCore": "Trace"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** To read the above `ApplicationInsights` configuration, you need to have [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights) nuget package installed. Otherwise the config will be totally ignored.

Comment: Thanks I just tested. With following i dont get any logs. {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "Microsoft": "Error",
      "VendorFormAPI": "Trace"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "InstrumentationKey": "xxx",
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace"
      }
    }
  },

Comment: Could be related to my configuration then. I added by Startup.cs.

Comment: You have to set the log levels for ApplicationInsights separately. `{"Logging":{"LogLevel":{"Default":"None","Microsoft":"Error","VendorFormAPI":"Trace"},"ApplicationInsights":{"InstrumentationKey":"xxx-36a5-4687-b1fc-xxxxxx","LogLevel":{"Default":"None","Microsoft":"Error","VendorFormAPI":"Trace"}}}}`

And as for startup.cs, you don't need to do anything else to setup logging. <br>
But yeah, make sure you have `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights` nuget package installed to read from the config file. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I feel I have tried all combinations :D I have this installed Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore. I removed everything from startup related to insights. I have following 
  "Logging": { "LogLevel": { "Default": "None", "Microsoft": "Error",  "VendorFormAPI": "Trace"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "InstrumentationKey": "",
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "None",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "VendorFormAPI": "Trace"
      }
    }
  },  Still no logs:( Only time I have logs if I have both inside and outside logging. But then I get everything logged.

Comment: And Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights

Comment: Even this does not provide any log:  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Trace",
      "VendorFormAPI": "Trace"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "InstrumentationKey": "xx",
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "Microsoft": "Trace",
        "VendorFormAPI": "Trace"
      }
    }
  },

Comment: I started all over on a blank weather template. I changed my original post to reflect the steps I have done.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. However the other answer helped in my case. Key needs to be at root level.